# Neural Network Prediction Interval

Tags: python, machine-learning, neural-network, prediction, confidence-interval

I created a neural network in Python for a regression problem. I would like to have a prediction intervals for each value. How would I go about approaching this since neural networks are nonlinear?

Comment: What do you mean by "prediction intervals"?

Comment: A range of values around each prediction where I am 95% certain the actual value lies.

Answer (score 1):

One approach is caliculate residual for the validation set, it will be having a distribution, calculate mean, variance of the residual distribution and if you are looking for 95% add +,- 2sigma to your prediction and that should be your prediction interval.

Answer (score 0):

My first though is using bootstrap and jackknife methodology. Using bootstrap method, you can compute empirical confidence interval for your prediction using sampling on your original dataset.

But you can find other answers in [this question](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/247551/how-to-determine-the-confidence-of-a-neural-network-prediction)